# Ajax function not showing values in django

Tags: python, django

Bit of a problem.  What i am trying to do is determine what date the user has selected from an option picker and print the value from a main.py function.
So let me show my set up.
first thing i have done is calculate the date and in my **views.py:**

```
def index(request):
#GOING TO PUT THE DATE DIFFERENCE CALCULATION HERE
the_uploaded_excel_file = excel_upload.objects.order_by('-id').first()
excel_file_path_from_db = the_uploaded_excel_file.my_excel_file.path
print(excel_file_path_from_db)
wb = load_workbook(excel_file_path_from_db)
ws = wb["Sheet1"]
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path_from_db, engine='openpyxl', sheet_name='Sheet1', skiprows=1)

max_date_column = ws.max_column
last_date_entered = ws.cell(row=1, column=max_date_column).value
todays_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
Date_difference = pd.date_range(start= last_date_entered, end=todays_date, freq='D')
print("last date entered was ")
print(last_date_entered)
print("todays date is ")
print(todays_date)
print("the days not done are")
print(Date_difference)
for date in Date_difference:
print(date)

return render(request, "index.html", {

'Date_difference': Date_difference
 })
```

Then I show the dates in my html:

```
<h2>
 {% for daterange in Date_difference %}
 <h5>{{ daterange|date:"d M Y" }}</h5>
 {% endfor %}
</h2>
    <select style="background-color: #ceedd0;" id="date_selector"
 onchange="what_date_has_been_picked()" name="filter_for">
 {% for daterange in Date_difference %}
 <option value={{ daterange }}>{{ daterange|date:"d M Y" }}</option>
 {% endfor %}
 </select>
```

this produces the following:

[image]

now what I want to do is to be able to print this result in my main.py. so i set up an ajax function.
the function from my main.js is called when the date selector is changed:

```
function what_date_has_been_picked(){
var obj = {'FileName': Date_difference};
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(Date_difference);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/send_date/',
        data: myJSON,
success: function (response) {
document.location.reload(true);
}
});
}
```

Then i set the **URL**:
path('send_date/', views.send_date, name="send_date"),

**views.py:**

```
def send_date(request):
return send_date(request)
```

**main.py :**

```
def send_date(request):
    selected_date = json.load(list(request.GET)[0])
 print(selected_date)
    data = {
 'status': 'ok',
 }
 return JsonResponse(data)
```

But the problem is the Date is not printed. Where did i go wrong?

Comment: Hi!, can you print/show  Date_difference in main.js  ? What type of var is? or function?

Comment: no i put window.alert(obj); in the what_date_has_been_picked() function but nothing got returned so the error must be with         var obj = {'FileName': Date_difference};
        var myJSON = JSON.stringify(Date_difference); maybe. im still trying to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

#### your problem

`Date_difference` is a context variable for the render of index function view on Django Fronted.
Your have write `Date_difference` on `main.js`.That is an static file content. Django serve this file but is not rending it.

#### quick solution

Pick the value of `<select>` with jquery

```js
function what_date_has_been_picked(){
    var myJSON = JSON.stringify({'FileName': $("date_selector").val()});
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/send_date/',
        data: myJSON,
        success: function (response) {
        document.location.reload(true);
        }
    });
}
```

If you need the text instead of value change the method from `.val()` to `.text()`

#### others in main.py

You can't convert a string to json with `json.load`

for obtain GET parameters:

```
    selected_date = json.load(list(request.GET)[0])
```

better replace with this

```
parameter = request.GET.get('FileName')
```

And then you can construct a JSON with this data.